# PHP　PDOでSQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, mariadb

PHPにて画面上部にて条件を入力し、画面下部にて結果一覧を表示する画面を作成しています。
where句を動的にしようと考え、試しに項目を1つで動的SQLを試みた（97行目～108行目）
のですが、108行目でSQLSTATE[HY093]エラーが出ます。

以下の記事を見て確認してみたのですが、スペルミスも見つからず、パラメーター数の不一致も見つからず、原因が不明です。

["SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number" あるある](https://qiita.com/sefp-maru/items/b8850c752def93106e34)

念のため、全エラーは下記です。

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\news_table.php:108 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\news_table.php(108): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\news_table.php on line 108
```

原因調査にご協力いただければ幸いです。

ソースコードを添付します。

```
<?php
try{
    require_once("db_connect.php");
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$SERV;dbname=$DB;charset=$CHAR",$USER,$PASS);
}
catch(PDOException $e){echo "次がエラーの内容です。;" .$e->getMessage();
}

$sdate = $_POST['sdate'] ?? "";
$edate = $_POST['edate'] ?? "";
$title = $_POST['title'] ?? "";
$content = $_POST['content'] ?? "";
$status = $_POST['status'] ?? "";
$clear = $_POST['clear'] ?? "";

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang=ja>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>News一覧</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Salon Yuri-rinの管理者ページ">
        <!--リセットcss-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css">
        <!--css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/news_style.css">
        <!--レスポンシブ対応-->
        <meta name="viwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!--Googleフォント-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sawarabi+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shippori+Mincho:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>News一覧</h1>
        <table class="search_table">
        <form class="conditions" name="conditions" id="conditions" action="news_table.php" method="post">
            <tr id="date" class="date">
                <td><label for="sdate">日付</label></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" value="<?=$sdate?>"></td>
                <td><label for="edate">～</label></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="edate" id="edate" value="<?=$edate?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="title">タイトル</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?=$title?>"></td>
                <td><label for="content">内容</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="content" id="content" value="<?=$content?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td><label for="status">ステータス</label></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="status" id="status">
                        <option value="0" 
                            <?php if($status === '0')
                                {echo 'selected';}
                                    else if($status === '1')
                                    {echo '';}
                                        else {echo '';}?> 
                                
                        >未選択</option>
                        <option value="1"  
                            <?php if($status === '1')
                                {echo 'selected';}
                                    else if($status === '0')
                                        {echo '';}
                                        else {echo '';}
                                ?>
                            >未公開</option>
                        <option value="2"  
                            <?php if($status === '2')
                                {echo 'selected';}
                                    else if($status === '0')
                                        {echo '';}
                                        else {echo '';}
                                ?>
                            >公開</option>
                    </select>           
                </td>
        </form>
        </table>
        <button type="button" form="conditions" class="search_button" id="clear" name="clear" value="clear">クリア</button>
        <button type="submit" form="conditions" name="search_button" class="search_button" id='search_button' value="clear">検索</button>
        <table class="tablehead">
            <tr>
                <th class="header">日付</th>
                <th class="header">タイトル</th>
                <th class="header">内容</th>
                <th class="header">公開ステータス</th>
                <th class="header2">
                    <form class="create" action="news_create.php">
                        <button type="submit" name="button" value="登録" class="button_a">登録</button>
                    </form>
                </th>
                <th class="header2"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['search_button'])){
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = ('select * from news where 1=1');
                if(isset($_POST['sdate'])){
                        $sql .= "and str_to_date('pub_date','%Y-%m-%d') >= str_to_date(':sdate','%Y-%m-%d')";
                    }
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                if(isset($_POST['sdate'])){
                    $stmt->bindvalue("sdate", $_POST['sdate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}?>

            <?php foreach($row as $data):?>
            <form action="?" method="post" class = "newstblform">
                <div class = "table1">
                    <table class="newstable">
                        <tr>
                            <input type="hidden" name="seq" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['id'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id="seq">
                        <td class="dt">
                            <label>
                                <input type="text" name="pub_date" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['pub_date'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id="sei" readonly="readonly">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dt">
                            <label>
                                <input type="text" name="title" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['title'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id=mei readonly="readonly">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dt">
                            <label>
                                <input type="text" name="content" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['content'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id="sei_kana">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dt">
                            <label>
                                <input type="text" name="status" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['status'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id="sei_kana">
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="bt">
                            <input type="submit" name=button value="修正" formaction="news_update.php" class="button_a">
                        </td>
                        <td class="bt">
                            <input type="submit" name=button value="削除" formaction="news_delete_conf.php" class="button_a">
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php require_once('newslist_chk_js.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset($_POST['sdate'])` が true のとき， `$sql` は

```
select * from news where 1=1and str_to_date('pub_date','%Y-%m-%d') >= str_to_date(':sdate','%Y-%m-%d')
```

となると思います．
ようは `and` の前にスペースが無いため SQL 的にエラーになっていると推測しました．

```php
$sql = ('select * from news where 1=1');
if(isset($_POST['sdate'])){
    $sql .= " and str_to_date('pub_date','%Y-%m-%d') >= str_to_date(':sdate','%Y-%m-%d')";
}
```

みたいな感じで，and の前にスペースを入れましょう

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。該当箇所は修正しましたが、まだ同じエラーが出ます。因みに101行目と105行目の条件は、isset($_POST['sdate']) && $_POST['sdate'] != ''に変更しました。

Comment: すみません．プレースホルダーの方を見落としていましたが，SQL 的にはバインドするパラメータの数がおかしいと言われていますのでコチラを先に確認すべきでしたね．「:sdate」が文字列として扱われてしまっているので，

```php
$sql .= "and str_to_date('pub_date','%Y-%m-%d') >= str_to_date(':sdate','%Y-%m-%d')";
```

を

```php
$sql .= "and str_to_date('pub_date','%Y-%m-%d') >= str_to_date(:sdate,'%Y-%m-%d')";
```

に変えてみてください

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございました。